# Replace values from rows with specific values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, replace, minimum

I have a dataframe **df** [df dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir2DB.png) with three columns: ID, Range, and Min_Range (this last column is the result I'm looking for).
I want to obtain the df$Min_Range column by replacing non-NA values in df$Range with their corresponding (to ID) Min_Range_df$Min_Range value from the Min_Range_df dataframe [Min_Range_df dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZhUH.png).
Another way to look at it is that I want to get the minimum df$Range by group (ID) and replace the Range values with the minimum.

```
df <- matrix(data=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,10,15,20,30,35,40,45,50,NA,NA,NA,10,10,10,30,30,40,40,40,NA,NA,NA), ncol = 3)
colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Range", "Min_Range")

Min_Range_df <- matrix(data= c(1,2,3,10,30,40), ncol=2)
colnames(Min_Range_df) <- c("ID", "Min_Range")
```

Thank you!!

Comment: are you looking for a `merge`? `merge(df, Min_Range_df, by = "ID", all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: @bouncyball `merge` was also my first thought, but it creates a non-NA value for the `NA`-entry with `ID==3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Min_Range_New = ifelse(is.na(Range), NA, min(Range, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

which returns

```r
      ID Range Min_Range Min_Range_New
   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1    10        10            10
 2     1    15        10            10
 3     1    20        10            10
 4     2    30        30            30
 5     2    35        30            30
 6     3    40        40            40
 7     3    45        40            40
 8     3    50        40            40
 9     3    NA        NA            NA
10     4    NA        NA            NA
11     4    NA        NA            NA
```

Answer (score 1):

First to get the `Min_Range_df`

```
Min_Range_df <- aggregate(Range ~ ID, df, min)

  ID Range
1  1    10
2  2    30
3  3    40
```

Then using it to make your new column

```
df[,"Min_Range"] <- NA
df[,"Min_Range"][!is.na(df[,"Range"])] <- unlist(lapply(df[,"ID"][!is.na(df[,"Range"])], function(x) Min_Range_df$Range[grep(x,Min_Range_df$ID)]))

      ID Range Min_Range
 [1,]  1    10        10
 [2,]  1    15        10
 [3,]  1    20        10
 [4,]  2    30        30
 [5,]  2    35        30
 [6,]  3    40        40
 [7,]  3    45        40
 [8,]  3    50        40
 [9,]  3    NA        NA
[10,]  4    NA        NA
[11,]  4    NA        NA
```